# What counts as the Dawn of the Planet of the Apes?

Tags: plague-inc-evolved

With the addition of the Simian Flu came a few new achievements. One of them, I'm not quite sure what I need to do to get it.

> **Film Fanatic**
>   Recreate the setting of the Dawn of the Planet of the Apes film

Having seen the movie, I know that (movie spoilers)

> • It takes place in SF
>  • The apes take over the city
>  • It ends basically with the start of an APE v. Human war

Now, the scenario described in the beginning of the film details the Simian Flu itself, but what it describes is vague enough that it is basically how it happens in the game no matter what. **So what particular things need to happen to unlock that achievement?**

Comment: Maybe it's just "everyone catches simian flu"?

Comment: Some players believe they have got the pop-up news associated to this achievement, but the achievement didn't unlock itself. This **[topic](http://steamcommunity.com/app/246620/discussions/0/43099721663759378/)** on the Steam forums speculates that the achievement is currently bugged. Guess we have to wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately on windows it is currently bugged on PC but it is fixed for iOS. (unfortunately it may seem its fixed because people have it but it is a very low proportion which suggests they cheated it in.)

The achievement is quite simple to get if it is the same as iOS

You simply have to have a world where Apes dominate, basically more apes than people.

Try and make sure that you have a lot of apes just to be sure

Comment: Are you sure? [This post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/246620/discussions/0/43099721642752914/#c38596747770921896) and [this post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/246620/discussions/0/43099721501015357/#c35220315563403418) from the creator seem to indicate otherwise. They do say it is hard to get.

Comment: just saying how i got it and i still can't get it on steam